# How is the number of object in azure active directory calculated

Tags: azure-active-directory

The basic version of azure active directory allows up maximum of 500,000 objects.  We intend to load users (and add them to groups) via the graph api.

Say I have

- 10 users
- 5 groups
- each group has the 10 users added to it

Does that count as 10+5 = 15 objects or 10*5 = 50 objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that count as 10+5 = 15 objects or 10*5 = 50 objects?

In Azure AD, a group is an object.

So, in your scenario, the answer is 10+5 = 15.